# Overriding default FOSUserBundle template, no effect

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

Yep, I know there are other questions like these. I checked each one, but I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

My own template is located at:

**src/Grit/GritWsBundle/Resources/views/layoutBase.html.twig**

Which contains (hidden unnecessary markups):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, following the documentation I have created this structure to override FOSUserBundle template:

**src/Grit/GritWsBundle/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig**

In this file I'm extending the layoutBase.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'GritGritWsBundle::layoutBase.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    {% block fos_user_content %}
                    {% endblock %}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have already cleared the cache, installed and 'dump' assets.

Somehow it's not working, doesn't take effect. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your template in the wrong place. As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) you need to place your `layout.html.twig` at the `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig` (not inside your bundle).

If you want to override template in your bundle you need to override FOSUserBundle by yours. You can find information in the [link above](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) and on the [Symfony official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was placing the files inside my bundle, I didn't notice the app/Resources dir. Inattention blindness.

Answer (score 0):

To override the template, your file path and name needs to mirror the path and name of the template you are overriding. Rename from `templateBase` to `template`.

Be sure to clear the symfony cache afterwards to see your result