# Overriding FosUser password reset form

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am trying to change the way form errors are rendered in FosUser password reset form. I want to get error messages under password form, not above as in default.

This FormType

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('plainPassword', LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType'), array(
        'type' => LegacyFormHelper::getType('Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType'),
        'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-group has-feedback'
        ],
        'first_options' => array('label' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'New Password'
            ]
            ),
        'second_options' => array('label' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Repeat Password'
            ]),
        'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
    ));
}
```

Template

```
<body class="reset-page">
<div class="reset-box">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="">
            <img src="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="reset-box-body">
    {{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_resetting_reset', {'token': token})}) }}
        {% for passwordField in form.plainPassword %}
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                {{ form_widget(passwordField, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
                {{ form_errors(passwordField, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-error'} }) }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit" />

    {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

But in the result, all errors are rendered above form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding default FOSUserBundle template, no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729115/overriding-default-fosuserbundle-template-no-effect)

Answer (score -1):

Move the  {{ form_errors(passwordField, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-error'} }) }} section to wherever you want the errors to display and that should work. Right now the errors would display in the form as that is where they are being set. Hope that helps!